# How to access one Model data functions in another model inside function in magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, model

How to access one Model data functions in another model inside function in magento 2

Below is my override function Model 
NameSpace\modulename\Model\Rewrite\Quote

```
 public function createEmptyCart()
        {


            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
            $quote = $this->createAnonymousCart($storeId);

            $quote->setBillingAddress($this->quoteAddressFactory->create());
            $quote->setShippingAddress($this->quoteAddressFactory->create());

            try {
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Cannot create quote'));
            }
            //return $quote->getId();
            // die('helloss');
            return parent::createEmptyCart();

        }
```

I want to get that return functionality in below model

NameSpace\modulename\Model

```
public function customcart($point1, $point2) {
//here i want to get that above function quote Data how to get 
}
```

Below is my Constructor

```
 public function __construct(PointInterfaceFactory $pointFactory) {
        $this->pointFactory = $pointFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you function is inside some class name inside quote Folder you have to **add that class name** then the below code will work fine

```
public function __construct(\NameSpace\modulename\Model\Rewrite\Quote\QuoteManagement  $quoteObj){
  $this->quoteObj = $quoteObj;
}

public function customcart($point1, $point2) {
     $getfunctions =   $this->quoteObj->createEmptyCart();
}
```

Comment: yes class is class QuoteManagement

Comment: i updated my answer try now

Answer (score 1):

inside this file, **NameSpace\modulename\Model** you can get another model function using constuct method,

```
public function __construct(\NameSpace\modulename\Model\Rewrite\Quote $quoteObj){
  $this->quoteObj = $quoteObj;
}

public function customcart($point1, $point2) {
     $getfunctions =   $this->quoteObj->createEmptyCart();
}
```

Comment: i updated my question with my current constructor please let me know how to do it now because i am using that constructor